# Created nested struct schema SPARK

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Existing Columns of the DF:

```
|-- col1: string (nullable = true)
|-- col2: string (nullable = true)
|-- col3: struct (nullable = true)
|    |-- col3_1: struct (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- colA: string (nullable = true)
|    |-- col3_2: struct (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- colB: string (nullable = true)
|-- col4: string (nullable = true)
|-- col5: string (nullable = true)
```

I need to read only the following columns:

```
col1,col2, col3,
```

For the first 2 columns I can create the following schema:

```
val schema = StructType(Array(StructField("col1", StringType), StructField("col2", LongType)))
```

Schema for the nested struct:

```
StructType(Array(StructField("col1", StringType), 
StructField("col3", StructType(StructField("col3_1",StructType(StructField("colA",StringType))),StructField("col3_2",StructType(StructField("colB",StringType)))))
```

Error:

```
error: overloaded method value apply with alternatives:
```

Any suggestions to create the schema for the nested struct

Comment: why are you creating schema ? you can just select the columns that you want.

Comment: @jack I am reading a huge set of data from a lot of files. The schema I have given is just a example and it has lot of other columns. Hence reading the unwanted columns affects the performance.

Comment: you can do spark.read.parquet("path").select("col3.col3_1") if you only want col3._1 from col3. Thus you don't read the others

Comment: @jack I want a lot of others as well. Please stick to the question, if you want to contribute.

Comment: you can precise them the same way. It was just an example so that you see how you can select a column in a nested structure. to select col1 col2 and col3.
you do select("col1", "col2", "col3"). if you don't want all of the elements of col3, you need to precise them as I mentionned above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should try something like this or declare a `case class` for col3 and replace it in your schema:

```
val schema = StructType(Seq(  
    StructField("col1",IntegerType,false),
    StructField("col2",StringType,false),
    StructField("col3",StructType(Seq(  
                       StructField("col3_1",StructType(Seq(  
                       StructField("colA",StringType,false)
                         ))),
                       StructField("col3_2",StructType(Seq(  
                       StructField("colB",StringType,false)
                         )))
```